# Can AWS Lambda do Cross Account Activity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

Can we use AWS Lambda for cross account activity. For example, I want to store a Parameter in SSM Parameter store in multiple AWS Accounts. Imagine I have a Master AWS Account which has access to all other AWS Accounts. Now can I write a python script for storing the parameter and make use of AWS LAMBDA to perform this.

Comment: Yes, Lambda can cross account, its simply a compute function. As long as you have configured the permissions / policies correctly it can interact with and do almost anything your local could do.

Comment: What you say that you "have a Master AWS Account which has access to all other AWS Accounts", do you mean that the other accounts have IAM Roles that can be assumed by a User or Role in the master account? Like this: [Accessing and administering the member accounts in your organization - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html). If so, then the AWS Lambda function in the master account would need to **assume an IAM Role** in a child account. It would then have permissions to access resources in that account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Definitely. AWS services are by default explicitly denied access from anywhere. Thats where [AWS IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) (Identity & Access Management) came into the picture.

[Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

[image]

Let say you have a master account that has a services needed by multiple accounts. The first thing you will do is provision the resource from that master account and then by doing so you are applying right policies that will give an access to the other accounts.

Lastly, some other services are protected by layers of protection such as NACL's for network layer protection and Security Groups for application layer protection. For this services that are protected by layers mentioned, you simply just need to check if these layers accepts and send traffic from the application ports that you're are using.

e.g. EC2 Security Group - Ingress Rule: `80, 443 0.0.0./0`

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine I have a Master AWS Account which has access to all other AWS Accounts.

This is usually setup by [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/). It helps with management and governance of all your accounts in a unified way.

System manager, which include Parameter store has [special provisions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-systems-manager.html) for working with AWS Organizations:

> You can synchronize operations data across all AWS accounts in your organization by using Organizations and Systems Manager Explorer.

The generall cross-account concepts have been addressed by other answer.

Comment: I can't find any reference to use of SSM Parameter Store within an organization in the special provisions links.